# Incredible low visits/day

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

Just caught a glimpse of site stats on Area51 and visits/day has an incredibly low value:

[image]

I cannot imagine such a low value with more than 900 avid users. Maybe on the 1st of January it is possible. Anyway, this value sounds terribly wrong.

How is this value computed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This must be a bug that lasts for over 2 weeks.

We are not alone:

- [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/187133)
- [Traffic isn't updated correctly on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309064/187133)
- https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/617/60

Comment: It stell seems to affect every single site in beta.

Comment: A bit  of 2019 follow-up might be useful here.  Was the bug fixed so that the *Area 51* stats are now correct, or does the problem persist?